# Same code 2 in 2 places within a worksheet, one works the other doesnt

Tags: excel, vba

I'm running the below code, that copies the info from a pivot to the first empty row of a list within a table, I need to do this 2 from different parts of the pivot to different tables (all within the same worksheet) hence I copied the code adapting the origin and destination cells, however the first works, the second doesn't, below my code (I have all in the same module within the VBA editor in case that matters).

```
Sub AiSLogCompletedCR()
' AiSLogCompletedCR
' AiS Status log entry for CR's on Completed Status
    Range("U19:Y19").Copy Range("E515").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

End Sub

Sub AiSLoginflightCR()
' AiSLoginflightCR
' AiS Status log entry for CR's on Completed Status
    Range("U20:Y20").Copy Range("N515").End(xlUp).Offset(3, 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Doesn't Work"?

Comment: Always specify the workbook and worksheet where your `Range` is, it may fix your problem.

Comment: thanks @Teamothy, I figure it out, the problem was with my data leaving empty spaces